# Instagram authorization scope doesn't work

Tags: c#, api, oauth, instagram

There are some questions about setting scope for Instagram authorization API, but after spending the whole day, I still can't figure out what is wrong :(

Here is my code:

```
var url = string.Format("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type=code&scope=likes+relationships", clientId, redirectUrl);

return Redirect(url);
```

I have added `likes` and `relationships` scopes to the URL. But, when user logs in, Instagram asks only for `Basics` and `Follow/Unfollow` permissions without `likes`. 
So I am not able to like on behalf of the user whatever I do.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you are adding scope as likes+relationships, instagram will give you basic permissions only. Instagram does not give you the permission to update relationship, post like and comments until you submit the app for review. With basic permissions you can view the people who liked your posts but you can not make like or comment to a post and can not update relationship status like follow/unfollow/block/unblock/ignore. For more details on submitting you app refer this https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116