# OAuthPermissionsException instagram

Tags: comments, instagram

when I post a comment in the instagram.It reminds me "This client has not been approved to access this resource." I don't know where to go wrong.
POST DATA：
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1114266205241331779_282407163/comments?text=this train is test data& access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx

Response：
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}

Comment: As said [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#post_media_comments) you should complete [this form](https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116) to request access to this endpoint (POST comments).

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137322/access-token-is-not-authorized-with-this-scope-relationship/30253686#30253686 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004784/instagram-authorization-scope-doesnt-work/30255943#30255943